# Probability of a sum of the best 3 dice out of 4, rolled and added 6 times

Tags: probability

I would like to calculate something but I probably lack the right notions of probability.

Here is the situation:
I roll 4 dice and I keep the 3 best, which I add together.
I repeat the operation 6 times and add up each result.

How to calculate, with a formula, the probability of having a total sum of 18, 19 etc up to 108.

Any idea how to go about it?

I have the probabilities of the result of a roll, which I obtained with a spreadsheet by dividing the number of occurrences of a value by the total number of possibilities, here 6^4.

```
ocurrences    sum   %
1             3     0.08%
4             4     0.31%
10            5     0.77%
21            6     1.62%
38            7     2.93%
62            8     4.78%
91            9     7.02%
122           10    9.41%
148           11    11.42%
167           12    12.89%
172           13    13.27%
160           14    12.35%
131           15    10.11%
94            16    7.25%
54            17    4.17%
21            18    1.62%
```

I did this to count the occurences of different sum of the 3 best dice rolling 4 :
[picture of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP4vb.png)

But for my problem, I have 16^6 possibilities, and the spreadsheet doesn't want to make that many lines xD.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having now done the best $3$ of $4$ you can take that number of occurrences as a random distribution that you can add to itself six times.  Make a column with numbers $6$ through $36$ as the value of two sets of three dice, then add the proper values from the table above to get the sum.  Now add three sets of this to get the sum for six.  At each step you are forgetting the details of where the number came from so the calculation does not explode in size.  For example, in your table there are $140$ ways for the best $3$ of $4$ to sum to $14$.  Your calculation of the best $3$ of $4$ goes through those, but now you just need the $140$ number going forward.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you get 6 points in two throws if you get 3 in the first and 3 in the second throw. You get 7 if you get 3/4 or 4/3 in two throws. You get for example 23 if you got 5/18, 6/17, 7/16, .., 18/5 and you add these probabilities up.

For three throws you add the probabilities for x points in the first two and y points in the third  throw, and so on.